# Show a subview on top of a QCView

Tags: macos, quartz-graphics, quartz-composer

It seems that no matter what hierarchy I use, a QCView is always drawn on top. Is there a way to display a subview on top of a QCView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QCView` compositing is quirky.  Try enabling Core Animation for your NSView hierarchy, and displaying the composition using `QCCompositionLayer` instead.

Comment: Thanks -- I've looked into this (ie from http://www.cimgf.com/2008/09/24/core-animation-tutorial-core-animation-and-quartz-composer-qccompositionlayer/) but I end up with a distorted image (looked like bits of memory were not getting drawn). Any example for what you're describing? Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like that might be uninitialized memory — make sure you have a `Clear` patch as the first layer in the root of your composition.